# Kriging : when it is said kriging is an unbiaised estimator, is that synonymous with saying it is an exact interpolator?

Tags: unbiased-estimator, interpolation, kriging

I feel like they are not synonymous, but I cannot intuitively explain the difference between "unbiased" and "exact." In other words, I am asking about the difference between the terms "unbiased" and "exact."

Comment: Where is it said that kriging is an unbiased estimator?

Comment: @Galen Many people make that claim, and indeed that's the origin of Kriging: it's intended to be a BLUP.  But that has *nothing* to do with being an exact interpolator.  That occurs only when the value of the variogram at the origin is zero.  If only to model measurement error, that value is usually positive.